# Validation form question bootstrap and javascript

Tags: javascript, forms, validation

thanks in advance for answering the question.

The goal in my form (as with many similar forms) is to check that

- text field is not empty
- password meets the criteria (to be honest, right now I would be happy with just anything in it)
- email has text before "@", the "@" and text after "@".

depending on whether all checks are okay, to display an alert with the message.

bootstrap:

```
<form>
    <div class="form-group">
    <label for="exampleTextarea">Course/Lecturer feedback</label>
    <textarea class="form-control" id="textArea" rows="3" placeholder="Please enter your feedback in this field. Your opinion matters and helps us to provide you with better serivce."></textarea>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Please enter your email address</label>
    <input type="email" class="form-control" id="emailAddress" aria-describedby="emailHelp" placeholder="Enter email">
    <small id="emailHelp" class="form-text text-muted">We'll never share your email with anyone else.</small>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="exampleInputPassword1">Please enter your password</label>
    <input type="password" class="form-control" id="password" placeholder="Password">
  </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="submitData()">Submit</button>

</form>
```

javascript

```
//comment validation function
function textFieldValidate(textField){
  var txtln = "";
  if (txtln !=="")
  return pattern.test(textField);
}

//email validation function
function isValidEmailAddress(emailAddress) {
    var pattern = new RegExp(/^(("[\w-\s]+")|([\w-]+(?:\.[\w-]+)*)|("[\w-\s]+")([\w-]+(?:\.[\w-]+)*))(@((?:[\w-]+\.)*\w[\w-]{0,66})\.([a-z]{2,6}(?:\.[a-z]{2})?)$)|(@\[?((25[0-5]\.|2[0-4][0-9]\.|1[0-9]{2}\.|[0-9]{1,2}\.))((25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|[0-9]{1,2})\.){2}(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|[0-9]{1,2})\]?$)/i);
    return pattern.test(emailAddress);
}

//password validation function
// at least one number, one lowercase and one uppercase letter
// at least six characters
function passwordValidate(password){
 var pw = new RegExp (/(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z]).{6,}/);
  return pw.test(password);
}

function submitData(){
  //retrieve the values
  if(textFieldValidate(textField) && isValidEmailAddress(emailAddress) && passwordValidate(password)){
    //send post request
    alert("Thank you for your feedback! We have sent this to KGB and you should expect a call any moment now...");
  }else{
    //display error message
    alert("Unfortunately information that you have entered was incorrect, please check the info and and resubmit");
    return;
  }
}
```

what I get at the moment is that my page refreshes and nothing happens.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, it looks like the issue was with the id in html which was called textArea and in function I called it textField.

Now... the other problem is that it doesn't really validate anything. Just the pop up appears...